# Messing with a runat="server" select list on the client

Tags: asp.net, forms

If I add some OPTION's to a select list from client side javascript, that seems to break this control. Is this what's supposed to happen?

IE, once I do this, I cannot get the value of my select list via going selectList.Value in c#.
I can't even seem to change this element to not be a runat=server, it seems to disappear from the request.forms collection.

```
var Items = response.d;
var options = '';
$.each(Items , function (index, Item) {
    options += '<option value="' + 
               Item.ItemID) + '">' + 
               Item.Name + 
               '</option>';
});
//alert(options);
$('#object_id').html(options);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there's some weirdness in general with select lists and innerHTML; not sure if that's what jQuery uses in the background, but you might be better off adding the option elements directly using append() rather than through html().

http://www.sitecrafting.com/blog/ltselectgt-tag-innerhtml/

Comment: Thanks for the response, it must be jquery not playing well with IIS here, or something. I can't get the select list value to post correctly no matter how I do it. Maybe I'm just writing the options out wrong or something, but it all looks fine to me. I tried Append() and that didn't help...Lost.....

Comment: I give up....Messing with the OPTIONS via jQUery seems to do some odd stuff. Thanks!